# Rust autocompletion not shown for items from the standard library

Tags: autocomplete, rust, visual-studio-code

I can't get working autocompletion on VS Code on Ubuntu 16.04.

I've installed rustup from https://www.rustup.rs/ and installed the "rust-lang.rust" package. This extension installed `rustfmt` and tried to use both `stable` and `nightly` toolchains.

If I type `std::` no suggestions are shown. Suggestions show on local `mod` import but not with the standard library. I tried to reinstall by removing via `uninstall.sh` and manually removing `~/.multirust` and `~/.cargo` and then installed again, but nothing changed.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have the `RUST_SRC_PATH` variable set. In my VS Code settings, I added

```
"rust.rustLangSrcPath": "/home/ilya/.rustup/toolchains/**your_toolchain**/lib/rustlib/src/rust/src/"
```

and it did the job. This option comes from the `kalitaalexey.vscode-rust` package.